# Getting complain message from radius server

Tags: linux, radius

I am very new to Radius server, please give some advice if you know. 
currently the basic configuration of Radius have been finished, while i am testing the server i got the following error:

`/usr/local/radius/bin/radtest user password localhost 0 testing123
radclient:: Failed to find IP address for radius
radclient: Nothing to send`

if you want to know further information for configuration please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears it can't resolve `localhost`, try `/usr/local/radius/bin/radtest user password 127.0.0.1 0 testing123`

Comment: Thank you for your advice,i have modified /etc/hosts and problem was solved.thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `/etc/hosts` file and add add the `hostname` of your server to the aliases list of `127.0.0.1`, like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 my-radius
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6 my-radius
```